# How to remove content inside curly braces{} along with the braces from a string in java?

Tags: java, regex

For example I have a string:-

```
High PM2.5 found in {$coordinate} and address is {$geoAddress} and solution found in {$solutionCoordinate} and address is {$solutionAddress}.
```

I want to remove everything in curly braces from this string and the output should be:-

```
High PM2.5 found in and address is and solution found in and address is.
```

Comment: This has been answered so many times

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes I was trying several regex in java to solve this and I got it. Message.replaceAll("\\{[^}]*\\}", "");

Answer (score 1):

I was trying several regex in java to solve this. I have got the right one,
String message = High PM2.5 found in {$coordinate} and address is `{$geoAddress}` and solution found in `{$solutionCoordinate}` and address is `{$solutionAddress}`.

```
message = message.replaceAll("\\{[^}]*\\}", "");
```